# AWS Cognito user SIGN IN with SMS MFA verification code not delivered

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-serverless

I have created AWS Cognito with user pool enabling MFA SMS Text Messages. Issued role to Cognito to send SMS Message. USD 1 Threshold is not yet covered for SMS. I have enabled the ENABLE SMS MFA in the user table

Problem is when user signin with username and password and next window requesting for SMS verification code ...But I am not receiving any SMS to my phone. When I disable the DISABLE MFA for the user at the user table, user is sucessfully logging to page once he enter the username and password.

I tried to check the cloudwatch logs but i could not see any data related to failed message

Answer (score 0):

SMS quota must have used.

Get your quota increase.   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/channels-sms-awssupport-spend-threshold.html